# Writing lazy curried in scala with multiple parameters

Tags: scala, haskell, lazy-evaluation, currying

I'm writing code for a game as an exercise to learn Scala after getting acquainted with Haskell. I started with an ADT as follows:

```
sealed class Circle(x: Double, y: Double, r: Double)

case class PlayerCircle (x: Double, y: Double, r: Double) extends Circle(x, y, r)

case class AICircle (x: Double, y: Double, r: Double) extends Circle(x, y, r)
```

I'm trying to write a lazy, curried val that does as follows (in Haskell pseudocode):

```
addToPlayer :: PlayerCircle -> Circle -> PlayerCircle
addToPlayer (PlayerCircle px py pr) (AICircle _ _ cr) = PlayerCircle px py (pr + cr)
addToPlayer player _ = player
```

I have the following:

```
def addToPlayer (wcircle : Circle) : PlayerCircle = wcircle match {
    case AICircle (_, _, wr) => copy(this.x, this.y, this.r + wr)
    case _ => this
}
```

What is necessary to make this function curried and lazy?

Edit: I've googled for the answer but haven't found any article of use so please help me with this one.

Comment: why do you want to curry it and make it lazy? Also currying is when you take a function that accepts **multiple** arguments and translate it into a sequence of functions each of which takes on argument.

Comment: I'm used to the Haskell paradigms, kinda. It's mostly a learning exercise.

Comment: but your function only takes one argument...how do you expect to curry it?

Comment: @I.K. Look at the Haskell-like code. It shows that instead of using this we pass the object as a parameter

Answer (score 2):

Here's a curried function example:

```
def addToPlayer(c: Circle, p: Player) = ... actual code...
def addToPlayer(c: Circle) = p: Player => addToPlayer(c, p)
```

Then you can do this:

```
val partial = addToPlayer(c)
val complete = partial(p)
```

This is lazy because `addToPlayer(c, p)` isn't run until both parameters are given.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this way

```
def addToPlayer(p: PlayerCircle)(c: Circle): PlayerCircle = c match {
  case AICircle(_, _, wr) => p.copy(p.x, p.y, p.r + wr)
  case _ => p
}
```